# Jenkins cron syntax not honoring timezone offset

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-groovy, crontrigger

I want to run my test jobs through Jenkins in EST time zone. In order to do that I used below cron scheduler but it doesn't seem to work. Jobs are not running in EST timezone.

`cron('TZ=America/New_York\n* * * * *')`

I substituted with all * to not give away my specific time.

Any insights. What am I doing wrong?

I tried this -
`"H 12 * * 1,3,5 TZ=America/New_York"`

But Jenkins throws following error -

`hudson.remoting.ProxyException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {spec=H 12 * * 1,3,5 TZ=America/New_York} for hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`